# Vue MS exchange SSO

Tags: vue.js, exchange-server

I'm buildinng a vue app and the client has requested that I enable sso from MS Exchange. Is this possible? If so does anyone know where I can find documentation. I have scoured the web but can't find anything on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Asking for off-site resources, tutorials, tools, or libraries recommendation is off-topic in here

Comment: maybe try technet? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=SSO%20exchange&ac=5